# How to input values to a scanner multiple times?

Tags: java, input, io, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a small program to help with my homework. It needs to square a number that is input and then sum all the squares and display them.

I came up with this but I have been getting errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Statistics {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sum = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nHow many times?  ");
    int times = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter the number to be squared: ");
        int squ = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(squ + "\n\n");
        sum += squ;
    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("\n\nSum = " + sum);
}
}
```

Here's the error I've been getting in the Eclipse console:

```
>     Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>       at Statistics.main(Statistics.java:16)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us those errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close a Stream, it closes the underlying stream as well.

You almost never need to close System.in and I don't suggest you do it in this case.

You should avoid wrapping the same stream more than once, unless you like confusion.  Unfortunately there is no simple way to prevent a developer from doing this but it is almost always a bug.

In short, you don't need to wrap `System.in` stream twice and in fact it will fix your problem.

This is how it might be written

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\nHow many times?  ");
int times = scan.nextInt();
double sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number to be squared: ");
    double d = input.nextDouble();
    double squ = d * d;
    System.out.println(squ + "\n\n");
    sum += squ;
}
System.out.println("\n\nSum = " + sum);
```

Comment: I'm not so well versed in Java yet, I'm just getting started. Could you explain what you mean by 'wrapping' System.in? 

What exactly do I need to change?

Comment: @aetos you are wrapping System.in now with a Scanner.  You don't need to change lines, but remove code you don't need.  You don't need two Scanners and you don't need to close them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's what @TheCrafter suggested but the error still appears after the first input.

Comment: @aetos you can't read a decimal as an integer.  try my example instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one scanner, you don't need a second one.

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nHow many times?  ");
        int times = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter the number to be squared: ");
            int squ = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(squ + "\n\n");
            sum += squ;
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println("\n\nSum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still an error after the first input. Here's what the console said: 


How many times?  
7

Enter the number to be squared: 
31.1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Statistics.main(Statistics.java:14)

Comment: @aetos `31.1` is not an integer.  Did you intended to use `double d = scan/.nextDouble(); double squ = d * d;` ?

Comment: @aetos Are you 100% sure that you copied everything I said exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry! My mistake, totally didn't realize the problem with the datatype! Thank you.

Comment: I change the datatypes to double but it still doesn't seem to work. Yes, I copied your code and changed the datatype of squ and sum to double. The error is as follows: 

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Statistics.main(Statistics.java:14)

Comment: @TheCrafter Fixed it.The problem was I used .nextInt() instead of .nextDouble(). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the close of your first scanner to the close to the second one after for-loop. 
Thats because your input-stream is closed with the first close and the second scanner cannot work.